# How to prevent user from navigating away when form is dirty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularJs app that requires authentication for most pages.  I've implemented the checks similar to http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2014/02/09/ui-router-in-angular-client-side-auth/

In angular.module('myModule').run(), I have:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams){
    if(toState.authenticate){
        event.preventDefault();
        var toUrl = $state.href(toState, toParams);
        var promise = authService.isAuthenticated();
        if (promise){
            promise.then(function(){
                // successful authentication proceed to requested state
                $state.go(toState.name, toParams, {notify: false, inherit: false}).then(function(state){
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('$stateChangeSuccess', state.self, toParams);
                });

            },function(){
                // failed authentication proceed to login
                $state.go('login', {
                    next: toUrl
                });
            });
        } else {
            $state.go('login', {
                next: toUrl
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is working just fine, however, when I tried to prevent a state change from within a controller when a form is dirty, it doesn't quite work.  Here is how I add the listener in my controller:

```
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if($scope.forms.myForm.$dirty) {
            event.preventDefault();
            modalAlert({
                text: 'You have unsaved changes, are you sure you wish to continue'
            }).result.then(function() {
                // User is OK leaving dirty  form, clear dirty flag to prevent this pop-up showing again and re-route
                $scope.forms.myForm.$setPristine();
                $state.go(toState, toParams);
            }, function() {
                // Cancelled request, stay on dirty form, don't need to do anything
            });
        }
    });
```

Basically, what is happening, is the first $stateChangeStart is called, the auth is resolved, and it does a $state.go() to the next state we were going to.  Meanwhile, the modal pops up asking to confirm and if I hit cancel, it reverts back to the previous state, but all my changes are gone because the auth checking already changed the state and lost all my changes.  If the page I'm going to does not require authentication, then it works as expected.

How can I make my controller's $stateChangeStart execute first?

Comment: This is a valid question, I don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: Your authentication event listener is broken. You're preventing the state change every time they try to navigate to a protected state. It should synchronously check if the state is protected, and if the user is not authorization.  Only then should it call evt.preventDefault().  By firing the $stateChangeSuccess event manually you are bypassing the entire $state.transitionTo mechanism and not really transitioning.

Comment: The Auth Service has an http request, so I'm not sure if synchronous check is correct.  If we don't do the evt.preventDefault() during async, then the screen will flicker with the desired page and then redirect to login when the promise is resolved and the user isn't authorized.